# Rounding separate values in a list at the same time

Tags: python, rounding

I would like to write something which looks a bit like what I currently have in the following definition:

```
def rounding( sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4 ):

    if () <= 700.:
        round(object, -1)
    elif () <= 1000.:
        round(object, (-1*5))
    elif () <= 10000.:
        round(object, -2)
    elif () > 10000.:
        round(object, -3)
    else:
        print "Error"

    return [ sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4 ]
```

I am really a beginner to all of this and I've probably made some horrendous mistakes in the above code. What I basically have is previously calculated these 4 values sp1, sp2 etc. I then want to be able to round these values all at the same time but depending on their individual value, they must be rounded by different amounts.

```
If 'sp' <= 700 : rounded to nearest 10
700 < sp <= 1000 : rounded to nearest 50
1000 < sp <= 10000 : rounded to nearest 100
10000 < sp : rounded to nearest 1000. (not code)
```

If something could help me I would be very grateful, thank you!

Comment: Can you explain your motivation for such peculiar rounding function?

Comment: It's just a task I've been given, not by my own personal choice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part is rounding to the nearest 50. That can be achieved by doubling the number, then rounding to the nearest 100, then halving the number again. At least that's the easiest way I can think of.

```
def nearest_50(n):
    return round(n*2, -2)/2
```

As for the rest, your code is not that far away from a correct solution. As Ignacio suggested, you should only round one value at a time

```
def my_round(n):
    if n <= 700:
        return round(n, -1)
    elif n <= 1000:
        return nearest_50(n)
    elif n <= 10000:
        return round(n, -2)
    else:
        return round(n, -3)
```

Then round a list of numbers like this

```
mylist = [... some numbers ...]
rounded = [my_round(n) for n in mylist]
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you =) The only thing is, when I try to test it, it skips the if statement and therefore doesn't work. Do you know why it does this?

Comment: I just can't seem to get anything to work. Are there any imports or anything I have to do? Sorry to be a pain but I don't understand where I'm going wrong!

Comment: Hm, maybe your indentation is broken? Make sure your code is indented with 0, 4 or 8 spaces respectively, no tabs.

Comment: No it's fine, I'm not quite sure but thank you so much again for your help, I liked the clear and simple answer!

Comment: You're welcome. The code should work fine if you just copy all code blocks from above into a file and replace `... some numbers ...` by yours.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that rounds a single value, then use a list comprehension to pass all the values through it one at a time.

Comment: I've tried something like that but I'm having difficulties calling the function for a particular value. Like I said I'm really a newbie to all of this.